# How to change router directly on vuex store (using composition API)?

Tags: vuex, vue-router, vuejs3, quasar-framework, vue-composition-api

what i'm trying on my store:

```
import router from 'vue-router'
export function router ({ commit, getters, dispatch }, payload) {
  console.log('test:', router)
  router.push({ path: '/admin/products' })
}
```

but it returns router 'undefined'.

What is the proper way to import router inside an composition api store ?

I know that i can import router by:

import Router from '../../router'

BUT... how can i apply a router change ? as it imports all my router file.

Here is my router index.js file:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/client.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/client/Index.vue') }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/admin',
    component: () => import('layouts/admin.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/admin/Index.vue') }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/products',
    component: () => import('layouts/admin.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/admin/Products.vue') }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/vendas',
    component: () => import('layouts/admin.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/admin/CheckoutPurchases.vue') }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/products/createProduct',
    component: () => import('layouts/admin.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/admin/CreateProduct.vue') }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/checkout',
    component: () => import('layouts/checkout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/checkout/Index.vue') }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/membro/:id',
    // beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => AuthGuard(to, from, next, store),
    component: () => import('layouts/basic.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/checkout/CheckoutMember.vue') }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/adminlogin',
    // beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => AuthGuard(to, from, next, store),
    component: () => import('layouts/basic.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/admin/Adminlogin.vue') }
    ]
  },
  // {
  //   path: '/productMember',
  //   component: () => import('layouts/basic.vue'),
  //   children: [
  //     { path: '', component: () => import('pages/checkout/Memberlogin.vue') }
  //   ]
  // },
  {
    path: '/obrigado/:id',
    component: () => import('layouts/checkout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/checkout/Thanks.vue') }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/checkout/:user/:product',
    component: () => import('layouts/checkout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/checkout/Index.vue') }
    ]
  },
  // Always leave this as last one,
  // but you can also remove it
  {
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)*',
    component: () => import('pages/Error404.vue')
  }
]

export default routes
```

Answer (score 1):

import it from your actual **.js** file where you implemented it, not from node package and it should work

```
import router from '.../router.js'
```

Comment: Yes, it imports my router index.js file. How can i apply the router.push method ?

Comment: router.push("/admin/products")

Comment: Router.push returns no function.

Comment: write it all lower case like you did in import or edit your question and show us exactly what you are trying

Comment: import Router from '../../router'

  Router.push({ path: '/admin/products' })

Comment: These are just routes not Router, you need to build it and export that not just routes. Something like this:     const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

Comment: How can i use this on my index.js router file ?

Comment: What do you mean index.js router file you said your router file is router.js?

Comment: index.js *, said wrong "router.js". It's my main router file, the second pasted code on my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239378/discussion-between-eeerrrttt-and-vojin-puric).

Answer (score -1):

In vue3, you should import router like this:

```
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

export default {
  setup() {
    const router = useRouter()
    // console.log(router) within onMounted() and you could find all routes is
    // in router.option.routes

    // redirect to homepage with query parameters
    router.push('/home', { id: 'xxxx' }) 
  }
}
```

And in your `router/index.js`, don't forget to add this:

```
// add this below your routes array.
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(), // url with # tag. You can also try the other
  routes: routes
})

// and export this router, not routes
export default router
```

In main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router/index'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router)
```